# php curl got 301 error , due to .htaccess

Tags: php, curl

my url restapi.mywebsite.com/employee is working when access via browser and POSTMAN, but when I curl php it return Moved Permanently error , but When I curl restapi.mywebsite.com/employee/index.php is working or  restapi.mywebsite.com/employee/index also fine, any clues ?

curl

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
        // set url 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.restapi.website.net/employee"); 

        //return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 



        echo $output = curl_exec($ch); 


        curl_close($ch);
```

I do not want my API url ends with the php extension and index. 
in my .htaccess I remove .php for index.php , my htaccess file is located inside the employee folder.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(index|id|create|delete)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^id/([0-9a-zA-Z+]+) id.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^delete/([0-9a-zA-Z+]+) delete.php?delete=$1 [NC,L]
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Try and add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` and it should automatically follow the redirect.

Comment: @ Magnus Eriksson it works thanks